# Jasper Reports exports well to PDF but not to Excel

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I'm new with Jasper Reports. I'm using 5.6.0 version and I can export some data to PDF and all fields are filled correct but when I try to export the same data to Excel, some fields are missing. The code I use it's the some on both clases (I have one class for each file export)

I also read that the template to export to PDF or Excel it's the same, so I don't know why fills all in PDF and not in Excel.

When I generate the PDF I pass all the data to:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,fileOutputStream);
```

And when I try to generate the Excel I call this funcion:

```
private void generateExcel(JasperPrint jasperPrint) throws IOException, JRException {
    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int status = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(SIXACOPWorkbench.getWorkbenchContext().getWorkbench().getFrame());
    if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        if (jFileChooser.getSelectedFile() != null) {
            String pathPDFs = (jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            File ficheroXLS = new File(pathPDFs+"//testing.xls");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ficheroXLS);
            exporterXLS.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporterXLS.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(fos));
            SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
            configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
            configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
            exporterXLS.setConfiguration(configuration);
            exporterXLS.exportReport();     
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

¿What I'm doing wrong when exporting to Excel?

Regards.

--- Update ---

I thoguht that if the PDF was generating well the Excel should do it but after read Dave Jarvis comment I'm updating with the jrxml:

1 - There are 3 informs: Inform A - Inform B - Inform C.
2 - **Inform A** has a header and footer and each row it's filled by **Inform B**.
3 - On **Inform B** the field that it's nos displayed on *Excel* it's *numberIndex*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SubinformeAtribucionesPorPropietario1" pageWidth="813" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="813" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="5af05b05-4f4d-4ff8-8bcb-ef8fa6c2b067">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.4641000000000008"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="178"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="Inform C" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="useNumberIndex" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <field name="fieldA" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="fieldB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldF" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numberIndex" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-1" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="1" width="53" height="19" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="974d00c4-7438-4d1f-92ff-6b720e113ecd"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{useNumberIndex}.booleanValue() ? $F{numberIndex} : $F{fieldC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-2" mode="Transparent" x="53" y="1" width="297" height="19" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="6dee9995-5734-4e42-b7e1-4c2cbe02739b"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldB}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport isUsingCache="true">
                <reportElement key="subreport-1" mode="Opaque" x="350" y="1" width="463" height="18" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a40d7385-072d-4cfc-a952-88b23a906b85"/>
                <subreportParameter name="name1">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="name2">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldE}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="Inform C">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Inform C}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource((Collection) $F{fieldA})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Inform C}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

4 - On **Inform B** there is a section filled by **Inform C** and on **Inform C**, the field that isn't display it's *extension*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SubinformeAtribucionesPorPropietarios" pageWidth="463" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="463" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="92989482-f12d-409d-bbbc-5168396c7b22">
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.9487171000000016"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <parameter name="paramA" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <parameter name="paramB" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <field name="fieldA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldB" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="extension" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fieldF" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-1" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="109" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4e1802bf-4ad3-4ed8-a378-e451866ef365"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-2" mode="Transparent" x="109" y="0" width="71" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a87c767c-8b6e-4dcf-b397-2412a752acaa"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldD}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-3" mode="Transparent" x="180" y="0" width="71" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="82e3a926-8f8f-41af-b478-db4eed521356"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldC}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-4" mode="Transparent" x="251" y="0" width="71" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b8954bd1-387e-4a5d-a762-9b1c19a86a78"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldB} + $F{fieldF}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-6" mode="Transparent" x="322" y="0" width="71" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="80594584-7236-407f-99b1-a5bd8b7cb91f"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{extension}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-7" mode="Transparent" x="392" y="0" width="71" height="16" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4792a89e-5852-4fcb-9f34-510d411a3cc3"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="221" y="3" width="101" height="17" uuid="45817d74-5748-40d9-ac2a-f07baa316e7e"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-8" mode="Transparent" x="322" y="3" width="70" height="17" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2d0cc5e5-1e50-4196-867f-a729d1c5a2f9"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramA}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField-9" mode="Transparent" x="392" y="3" width="71" height="17" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="19d787cb-e1df-473d-9f52-3c3aa7bed427"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="None">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="7" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{paramB}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Did you use `apache poi` lib?

Comment: Hi Ataur, I'm on a project and I can not change to Apache Poi :/

Comment: Is it a web project or desktop based?

Comment: I'ts a desktop project on Java.

Comment: @Aker666 `What I'm doing wrong when exporting to Excel` - Maybe you template is wrong. You should post the small sample to reproduce the problem (Java code + jrxml + screenshot)

Comment: If the template is wrong the PDF must generate wrong but the output it's correct. And the code it's the same for both, only changes the call to the function that exports and I've put on the question. Moreover I can`t take screenshot, it's a company project.

Comment: @Aker666: Overlapping elements in the JRXML can cause incorrect layouts for non-PDF formats. Please provide a minimum working example of the problematic JRXML code, without any company-specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if was a bug, but I copied the line of other textFieldExpression of the jrxml that was working, rename it to the value that wasn't displaying and now the value it's displayed.

What the hell...

Answer (score 0):

in ur jrxml design report column should not be overlapped. Because if you have two element that share some region, that will not properly rendered and results in missing column or data in excel reports.